Jython API copy method does not seem to work
I am using the following Python 2 method, in which the parameter of the method is a Jython object (task) :
def getTaskPosition(task):
    """Gets the current position of the task in its container (phase or group task)"""
    index = 1
    for t in task.container.tasks:
        if task.id == t.id:
            return index
        index += 1

Further ahead in my Python 2 script, I use the **copyTask ** method from the Jython API :
https://apidocs.digital.ai/jython-docs/#!/xl-release/22.2.x//service/com.xebialabs.xlrelease.api.v1.TaskApi
This Jython method receives 3 arguments :
copyTask(String taskId, String targetContainerId, int targetPosition)
The 3d argument (targetPosition) is an integer returned from the 1st method (getTaskPosition)
For some reason, in the context of XL-Release, the output error is "Index Out of Range. The index should be between 0 and 2", and I absolutely can not figure out why this is happening
I tryed out to cast targetPosition to an integer, and I tried out to hardcode 0, 1 and 2. Apart from that, I can not figure out what else I could do

The index is being started at 1 instead of zero, so it goes out of range. The function should be written like this to ensure the index is both accurate and zero indexed:
def getTaskPosition(task):
    for index, t in enumerate(task.container.tasks):
        if task.id == t.id:
            return index

Also, the function doesn't account for a default value when none of the task ids match. In that scenario, the function would return None. Somewhere in the code, the potential null value probably needs to be handled.
